# get all item in local storage

Tags: javascript

Hi i have this local storage and i want to get all item in the local storage with key buy user_film:

```
key: buy user_film{[""The Silence of the Lambs"",""fats and furiuos""]}
```

I try to get all item in local storage with key buy user_film:

```
var film=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("buy user_film")));
    var pos=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("buy user_film")).length;
    for(var i=0;i<=pos;i++){
        var value = localStorage[i];    
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("buy user_film",value));
    }
```

The output of the console is undefine. How can i do?

Comment: could you please explain better the question and fix the text formatting?

Comment: Why `film=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))`? Why do you parse `.getItem("buy user_film")` and then only store the length of the array instead of the array? Why `<=pos`? Why `localStorage[i]`? What is `.getItem("buy user_film",value)` supposed to do? -> Please have a look at how the [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) (and therefor `localStorage`) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some small confusing parts in your example.

1. You can use the keyname "buy user_film" but i will not recommended. Because you may have some problems with it later. (e.g. dynamic key names.)
2. 

> key: buy user_film{[""The Silence of the Lambs"",""fats and
> furiuos""]}

You can have objects inside an array but not vice versa

3.

> film=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("buy
> user_film")));

first you stringify and step later parse to an object. that makes no sense here right now.

4.

> var value = localStorage[i];

I didn't quite understand this part. That makes noc sense to iterate the storage by the length of the film array?
Maybe: you expect in the lcoalstorage an item with the name "The Silence of the Lambs"? than i suggest that you need condition like if(localStorage.has(film[i]))) {...}.

Noote: You mean: "fast and furious"

try this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("buy user_film"));
var pos = obj.length;
var i;
for(i=0;i<pos; i++){
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Andreas:  I didn't have time until just now. I just wanted to look at the code and boom. I saw the little error immediately and corrected it. Always this i. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Andreas ups :-o. corrected again. next time i try it out before i post an answer. goof idea. merci